# Google Chrome native form error event

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

Does Google Chrome and any other browser trigger an event when a field is not valid on submit? For example, if an e-mail address field is an invalid e-mail, Google Chrome will launch a popup that says "Please enter an e-mail address".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'invalid' event is dispatched.
See [Constraint validation](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#constraint-validation)